# RD connection issue

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to a client computer using the remote desktop connection. I have tried almost everything. The admin has access to the client system, but the user does not have access unless I type in the username in the 'Allow users to connect option' inside the client machine. It works, however, the remote control tab does not work in the user's properties as he connects to the client indefinitely. If I remove the user from 'Allow users to connect' on the client machine, I get the error
'The user is not authorized for login'. I am too exhausted. I've been pulling my hair for way too long on this now.
I use active directory and the server is windows server 2012 r2.

Answer (score 0):

The administrator account has full access to the client machine as you say because that's the way it works. Any other account in the client machine needs to be added to the remote desktop users in order to use it to connect to it, even though the account already exists. So what I suggest is that you add to the machine you're trying to connect the domain or local account to the remote desktop users group and after that I guess you wouldn't have more issues.

You can go the Remote Desktop Users Group by going to the Computer Management console (Windows key + R and type compmgmt.msc) and then under Local Users and Groups find the groups folder. Right click properties and add the user account. Hope it helps.